# Building a grammar from trees in python

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar, part-of-speech

I have a text corpus that contains sentences represented as trees with their Part of Speech tags. I want to build a system that can probably learn a probabilistic grammar from this tree structure. Are there any inbuilt python modules than can tackle this or do I have to have to build a parser?

Comment: You mean "trees", don't you?

Comment: Is this about parsing the trees (in which format are they stored?) or the sentences (which you don't have a grammar for, yet)?

Comment: for example:
(TOP (S (VP (VB List) (NP (NP (DT the) (NNS flights)) (PP (IN from) (NP (NNP Baltimore))) (PP (TO to) (NP (NNP Seattle))) (SBAR (WHNP (WDT that)) (S (VP (VBP stop) (PP (IN in) (NP (NNP Minneapolis))))))))) (PUNC .))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt find one. Had to implement my own parser using stacks. Honestly wasnt too much of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a grammer for parsing your text.
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch08.html#fig-depgraph0

then parse your text using nltk parser with this grammer.